# Como importo o creo registros en Python?

Tags: python, datos

es una pregunta muy sencilla soy nuevo en esto y aún no he podido encontrar la solución. Solo necesito saber como hacer el uso de registros en python. He visto que la palabra clave es #record y el llamado es "from record import record" (Sin comillas). Haciendo esto me declara que hay error: no moduled name 'record'.

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por registro? El concepto es muy genérico y depende de a qué te refieras puedes necesitar usar el módulo `struct` o, módulos de acceso a bases de datos, o `pickle`, o `json`...

Comment: `record` no es una palabra clave. `from record import record` significa que tienes un archivo `record.py` en tu proyecto, el cual contiene una función o variable llamada `record`, y que quieres usarla dentro de tu programa.